# How to remove cancel button on alertify prompt?

Tags: alertifyjs

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                alertify.prompt('Please enter password for authorization', function(evt, value) {
                    value = md5(value);
                    if (value != null && value == '$pass') {
                                    alertify
                          .alert('Success! Shifting to Happy Hour. ', function(){
                            alertify.message(window.location = `main_2.php`);
                          });   
                }else{
                    alertify
                          .alert('Invalid Password, Please Try Again.', function(){
                            alertify.message(window.history.back());
                          });


                }});


            </SCRIPT>");
```

I want to make to prompt to have the text input and ok button only. What will be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be hiding the cancel button. I have added a CSS to hide the Cancel button.

```js
alertify.prompt('Please enter password for authorization', function(evt, value) {
                    value = md5(value);
                    if (value != null && value == '$pass') {
                                    alertify
                          .alert('Success! Shifting to Happy Hour. ', function(){
                            alertify.message(window.location = `main_2.php`);
                          });   
                }else{
                    alertify
                          .alert('Invalid Password, Please Try Again.', function(){
                            alertify.message(window.history.back());
                          });


                }});
```

```css
.ajs-cancel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.11.1/alertify.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.11.1/css/alertify.min.css'>
```